# Recreate this graph of $2\sin(x)+1$

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I have been trying to create this graph with pgfplots and tikz. 
[image: The original image.]

I have most of it down but I cannot seem to get the axes centered like they are shown in the picture and have the tick labels on the sides like a boxplot as well as the labels only at intervals of $\pi$ on the x axis.

The code below gives me the pictured result below:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \begin{axis}
      [
      grid=major,
      axis lines = center,
      xmin=-2*pi-0.5, xmax=3*pi+0.5,
      ymin=-2, ymax=3,
      xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
      domain= -2*pi:3*pi
      ]
      \plot[smooth, samples=200, thick, color=blue, <->  ]{2*sin(deg(x))+1}; %deg() used to convert radians to degrees since pgfplots wnats degrees
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output of code above.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In code are marked lines which is added to your MWE:

```
    \documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}% <--- changed
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \begin{axis}
      [
      outer axis line style={draw=gray!50},% <-- added
      grid,
      xmin=-2*pi-0.5, xmax=3*pi+0.5,
      xtick={-6.28,-3.14,0,3.14,6.28,9.42},% <-- added
      xticklabels={$-2\pi$,$-\pi$,0,$\pi$,$2\pi$,$3\pi$},% <-- added
      ymin=-2, ymax=3,
      xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
      domain= -2*pi:3*pi
      ]
      \addplot[smooth, samples=200, thick, color=blue, <->  ]{2*sin(deg(x))+1}; %deg() used to convert radians to degrees since pgfplots wnats degrees
      \addplot[draw=none,color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {(-pi,1) (0,1) (pi,1) (2*pi,1)};% <-- added
  \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,3);% <-- added
  \draw[<->] (-6.78,0) -- (9.92,0);% <-- added
      \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah that's great! I'm seeing that you used the \draw commands to draw the axis lines yourself correct?

Comment: yes, because I use standard boxed axis for put ticks on graph outside.